# What makes Cialis cure Erectile Dysfunction permanently?

Tags: medications, cure, erectile-dysfunction

Referring to this published paper [Efficacy and safety of once-daily tadalafil in men with erectile dysfunction who reported no successful intercourse attempts at baseline](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23035781).

> The posttreatment intercourse success rate was 32% and 46% for
>   tadalafil 2.5 mg and 5 mg, respectively, in men with no successful
>   intercourse attempts at baseline.

My question is,

- Is the above result believable?
- If yes, what makes Cialis cure Erectile Dysfunction permanently?

Comment: It's not permanent. If you stop taking the medication, ED returns.

Comment: @JohnP, you have any studies that backup your claim?

Comment: http://www.cialis.com/ - Scroll down the info box on the front page: CIALIS does not: cure ED /increase a man’s sexual desire /protect a man or his partner from sexually transmitted diseases, including HIV /serve as a male form of birth control

Comment: @JohnP, obviously there is a contradiction here... do you have other sources that shed some light on this matter?

Comment: If you don't accept that the maker of Cialis states on their own webpage that it doesn't cure ED, then I'm not sure what will convince you. It can help *while you are taking it*, but it won't be a permanent thing if you stop taking it.

Comment: Sorry, but JohnP is right. The manufacturer clearly states that Cialis _does not_ cure ED. It's a treatment, not a cure.

Comment: @JohnP, in that case, would you like to write it up as a formal answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **Is the above result believable?** The results show treatment of symptoms of ED, if the medication stops then the symptoms will come back. So yes the results are believable one could say, but they are not permanent.
- **If yes, what makes Cialis cure Erectile Dysfunction permanently?**

> [CIALIS does not](http://www.cialis.com/):  Cure ED, increase a man's sexual desire, protect a
>   man or his partner from sexually transmitted diseases, including HIV
>   or serve as a male form of birth control

As [@JohnP](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3142/what-makes-cialis-cure-erectile-dysfunction-permanently/5201#comment5136_3142) said Cialis's effects are not permanent and all information on the drug can be found on the official drugs site, cialis.com

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, I find this study to be credible.

To understand why, let's start with some background:

Following prostate removal, or radiation treatment for prostate cancer, many men experience severe ED due to damage to nerves and blood vessels.  Some men recover the ability to have an erection over time, as tissues heal.

However, because the men are not having regular erections, there isn't enough blood flow into the penis to maintain healthy tissues.  For this reason, many urologists will prescribe a daily dose of Cialis (tadalafil) to maintain the health of the penis, and promote healing.

This is an "off label" use of Cialis.  The urologists are prescribing it for something other than its intended and approved purpose.  And the manufacturers cannot claim that it is effective for this purpose, because the FDA has not approved it.

So, the idea that Cialis might encourage healing and regeneration of erectile tissues by maintaining healthy blood flow is well known, despite lack of FDA approvals, or manufacturer claims.

Of course, it would be premature to jump to conclusions based on a single study; it's important to understand how clinical studies work, and especially how they relate to FDA approval for specific uses (in the United States).

---

**Citations**

[Erectile preservation following radical prostatectomy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3126086/)

[Tadalafil therapy for erectile dysfunction following prostatectomy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4485415/)

Comment: I have removed the self promotion link. You can occasionally reference your own site if it is pertinent, and you can always put your links in your profile. However, self promotion without disclosure is not permitted on SE sites.